# Why is my updateOne() not working on mongo, with no error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Current code

```
async function checkPoint(arrayPoint, collection, origin){
    const trial = await collection.findOne({ 'Points': { $exists: true, }})
    if(trial == null){
        collection.insertOne({Points: ['floater', '1']})
        trial = await collection.findOne({ 'Points': { $exists: true, }})
    }
    foundPoint = false;
    pointArray = trial.Points
        for(let i = 0; i < pointArray.length; i++){
            newPoint = pointArray[i]
            newID = newPoint[0]
            newValue = newPoint[1]
            if(newID == arrayPoint){
            console.log("It seems we have data ! Aha !" + arrayPoint )
            val = parseInt(newValue)
            val = value + 1;
            val = value.toString();
            newValue = val;
            pointArray[i] = [newId, newValue]
            await collection.updateOne(trial, {$set: {'Points': pointArray}} )
            foundPoint = true
            }
            else{
            console.log("It seems id: " + arrayPoint + " doesn't match id " + newID)
            }
        }
        if (foundPoint == false){
            pointArray.push([arrayPoint, '1'])
            await collection.updateOne(trial,{$set: {'Points': pointArray}} )
        }
}
```

The code executes itself perfectly, but doesn't change 'points' without anything

I tried basic bug fixing, looking at documentation and couldn't find anything about passing arrays.

the value it passes is

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 0
}
```

Comment: @Do Dugal McSmith , Please add some other key for updateOne query after that you can check

Comment: Can I just know why my code isn't working? @WernfriedDomscheit, I don't think that acomplishes what I need.

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar What do you mean sorry? I'm new to this

Comment: Does it really execute without an error? I got so many, that I stopped checking. For example you mix `val` / `value` and `newID` / `newId`

Comment: How can you expect an successful `updateOne()` if your code does not work at all? You code does not make much sense, post some valid code. Maybe try `for (let i = 0; i < pointArray.length; i++) {
   newPoint = pointArray[i]
   newID = newPoint[0]
   newValue = newPoint[1]
   console.log(``newPoint => ${tojson(newPoint)}\nnewID => ${newID}\nnewValue => ${newValue}``)
}` to see what nonsense you are doing. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do you mean by "*the value it passes is*" - What is "*it*"? Maybe use `console.log(tojson(trial) + tojson({'Points': pointArray}) )` before the `updateOne(trial, ...)`, I guess then you will see the problem.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have logged the code. The input. And the output. It logs the right value to push. The value is simply unchanged for some reason. The code. works. It gives the value I need. I just need the updateOne to be pushing the value which it isn't pushing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I refuse to give an answer if required information are not delivered or if comments are rejected, but I make an exception. If you would have run `console.log(tojson(trial))` as suggested in my comment, you would see immediately that `trial` is

```
{ _id: ObjectId("6389ea1d06..."), Points: { ["floater", ["1", "NaN"] ] }
```

but not

```
{ _id: ObjectId("6389ea1d06..."), Points: { ["floater", "1"] }
```

as you may assume.

Your problem is this code:

```
pointArray = trial.Points // <- pointArray  is not a copy of trial.Points, it is a reference to original object
for (let i = 0; i < pointArray.length; i++) {
   newPoint = pointArray[i]
   newID = newPoint[0]
   newValue = newPoint[1]
   if (newID == arrayPoint) {
      console.log("It seems we have data ! Aha !" + arrayPoint)
      val = parseInt(newValue)
      val = value + 1;
      val = value.toString();
      newValue = val;
      pointArray[i] = [newId, newValue]
      await collection.updateOne(trial, { $set: { 'Points': pointArray } })
      foundPoint = true
   } else {
      console.log("It seems id: " + arrayPoint + " doesn't match id " + newID)
   }
}
```

Maybe it becomes clear if I rewrite it. Below code does exactly the same:

```
for (let i = 0; i < trial.Points.length; i++) {
   newPoint = trial.Points[i]
   newID = newPoint[0]
   newValue = newPoint[1]
   if (newID == arrayPoint) {
      console.log("It seems we have data ! Aha !" + arrayPoint)
      val = parseInt(newValue)
      val = value + 1;
      val = value.toString();
      newValue = val;
      trial.Points[i] = [newId, newValue] // <- here is the problem
      await collection.updateOne(trial, { $set: { 'Points': trial.Points } })
      foundPoint = true
   } else {
      console.log("It seems id: " + arrayPoint + " doesn't match id " + newID)
   }
}
```

I would suggest to update collection like this:

```
await collection.updateOne({ _id: trial._id }, { $set: { 'Points': trial.Points } })
```